# ui-grid (3.0.0 unstable) cellFilter with dates issue

Tags: angular-ui-grid

ui-grid (3.0.0-rc.16) doesn't work well when using filtering dates.
Filtering on other fields works well.

Here comes a punker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/b9NSk0
```

Try to start entering 2014 for any date.

Bug or I missed something?

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.i18n']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    eventName: "event1",
    eventDateRaw: new Date(1416396274368),
    eventDateFormatted: new Date(1416396274368)
  }, {
    eventName: "event2",
    eventDateRaw: new Date(1416352423803),
    eventDateFormatted: new Date(1416396274368)
  }];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'eventName', width: "20%"
    }, {
      name: 'eventDateRaw', width: "40%"
    }, {
      name: 'eventDateFormatted', width: "40%",
      cellFilter: 'date: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"'
    }],
    enableFiltering: true
  };
});
```

br
remy44

Answer (score 2):

Try and add a type:

```
{
    name: 'eventDateFormatted', width: "40%",
    cellFilter: 'date: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"',
    type: 'date'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Inverting your quotes, so the parameters are passed in using single quotes.

`javascript
cellFilter: "date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss'"`

Answer (score 0):

cellTemplate: '{{row.entity.delivery_month | date:"yyyy MMM"}}',

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it doesn't work on declarative phase but this should work:

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.i18n']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [{
    eventName: "event1",
    eventDateRaw: new Date(1416396274368),
    eventDateFormatted: new Date(1416396274368)
  }, {
    eventName: "event2",
    eventDateRaw: new Date(1416352423803),
    eventDateFormatted: new Date(1416396274368)
  }];

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'eventName', width: "20%"
    }, {
      name: 'eventDateRaw', width: "40%"
    }, {
      name: 'eventDateFormatted', width: "40%"
    }],
    enableFiltering: true
  };
 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[2].cellFilter = "date:'dd/MM/yyyy'";
});
```

Pay attention to the last line